# How to take the value to a new page?

Tags: javascript

I have code for getting email domain from user's email input.

```
<input type="text" id="email" class="required form-control" maxlength="120" />

<script>
const email = "person@example.com";
const [, domain] = email.split("@");
document.getElementById("button").setAttribute("href", `http://${domain}`)
</script>
```

Button for success page:

```
<a id="button">Link</a>
```

How can I transfer the value from sign up page to a success page?

Comment: Put in localStorage? In a cookie? add it to the URL you navigate to?

Comment: You can use either localStorage or sessionStorage.

Comment: Or use a query string in the link?

Answer (score 1):

**If the page it's on the same domain:**

- Use localStorage to store the information, read it when the new tap/redirection finishes

**Otherwise:**

- Figure if you can set field value by setting a query in the url, something on the lines of: http://www.page-form.com/form?email=person@example.com&cc=person2@example.com